# Converting double to string in Oracle pro*c

Tags: sql, c, oracle

Is there any way to convert a double value to string without losing any digit in Oracle pro*c? The precision varies as the column from which value is fetched is NUMBER(10,8)

Comment: What did you try? Did you try TO_CHAR?

Comment: Converting any `double` to a string with 17 _significant_ leading digits is usually sufficient.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True, but if the requirement is to get a decimal number from the database in C as a string, then why convert to double first? If you really want to do any calculations with the number, then a decimal library (e.g. decNumber C lib) must be used. Even then, you would get it from the DB as a string and create a decimal number data type from the string (see, for example, decNumberFromString in the decNumber lib).

Comment: @StephanSchlecht "to get a decimal number from the database in C as a string, then why convert to double first?" --> speed.  Binary floating point meets most needs when used well -but not all.  "really want to do any calculations with the number, then a decimal library (e.g. decNumber C lib) must be used." --> Next version of C may have decimal floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Like it was mentioned in comments you can use TO_CHAR to convert to a string. In Pro*C it would look something like this:

```
EXEC SQL DECLARE num_test_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TO_CHAR(num) FROM numtest;
```

Then you can fetch it into a variable:

```
EXEC SQL FETCH num_test_cursor INTO :number_string;
```

Finally with

```
number_string[strcspn(number_string, " ")] = '\0';
```

you can remove all padding space characters at the end.

**Test**

Create a table in an SQL client, e.g. SQLPlus, and fill it with some test entries:

```
CREATE TABLE numtest ( num NUMBER(10,8));
INSERT INTO numtest VALUES (99.99999999);
INSERT INTO numtest VALUES (3.141592654);
INSERT INTO numtest VALUES (0.00000001);
INSERT INTO numtest VALUES (1.23);
```

**Complete, Self-contained Pro*C Program**

```
exec sql begin declare section;  
char *connectString = "scott/tiger@pdb";
int limit; 
char number_string[11 + 1]; //number(10,8) + NUL 
exec sql end declare section;  
exec sql include sqlca;  

#include<stdio.h>  
#include<conio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  

int main(void) {  
    exec sql connect :connectString;
    if(sqlca.sqlcode == 0) {  
        printf("connected to db\n");  
    } else {  
        fprintf(stderr, "failed:%s (error code=%d)\n", sqlca.sqlerrm.sqlerrmc, sqlca.sqlcode);  
        exit(1);
    }
    EXEC SQL SELECT COUNT(*) INTO :limit FROM numtest; 
    printf("row count: %d\n", limit);

    EXEC SQL DECLARE num_test_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TO_CHAR(num) FROM numtest; 
    EXEC SQL FOR :limit OPEN num_test_cursor; 

    int row;
    for(row = 0; row < limit; row++) {
        EXEC SQL FETCH num_test_cursor INTO :number_string; 
    
        number_string[strcspn(number_string, " ")] = '\0';
        printf("number as string: \"%s\"\n", number_string);
    }
    
    _getch();  

    return 0;
}
```

The debug outputs of the program confirm the desired result:

```
connected to db
row count: 4
number as string: "99.99999999"
number as string: "3.14159265"
number as string: ".00000001"
number as string: "1.23"
```